# Chrome Extension Erorr: rules.json: Rule with index 1 couldn't be parsed. Parse error: 'id' is required

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

can't upload my extension. Have an erorr rules.json: Rule with index 1 couldn't be parsed. Parse error: 'id' is required.

manifest.json file:

```
{
    ...
    "permissions": ["declarativeNetRequest", "declarativeNetRequestFeedback", "webRequest", "activeTab", "scripting"],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "resources": ["content_main.js", "./background.js"]
        }
    ],
    "declarative_net_request": {
        "rule_resources": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "enabled": true,
                "path": "rules.json"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

rules.json file:

```
[
    {
        "version": 3,
        "rules": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "priority": 1,
                "action": {
                    "type": "send_message",
                    "extension_id": "myextension123",
                    "message": {
                        "type": "complete_url",
                        "completeUrl": "{url}"
                    }
                },
                "condition": {
                    "urlFilter": "https://card.wb.ru/cards/v1/detail?*"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I can't figure out what id is required if it is explicitly set, I tried to look here, but I didn't find an error https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/#type-Ruleset

I tried to solve this problem with chatGPT, but he say "all ok"

Comment: try defining ID as an int rather than a string

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

there's right code manifest.json:

```
    "declarative_net_request": {
    "rule_resources": [
        {
            "id": "intercept_requests",
            "enabled": true,
            "path": "rules.json"
        }
    ]
}
```

rules.json:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "priority": 1,
    "action": {
        "type": "block",
        "extension_id": "myextension123",
        "message": {
            "type": "complete_url",
            "completeUrl": "{url}"
        }
    },
    "condition": {
        "urlFilter": "https://card.wb.ru/cards/v1/detail?*"
    }
}
```

]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).